# In C++, how to declare a data structure in header file , while it is defined in source file?

Tags: c++, typedef

Say I want to use typedef to define a new set MyTypeSet with customized hash and comparator functions in a source file. I want to hide all the implementation details in the source file.

```
typedef std::unordered_set<MyType, MyTypeHash, MyTypeKeyEqual>
MyTypeSet;
```

Then I want to declare MyTypeSet in header file for other modules to use. But I do not want to expose MyTypeHash and MyTypeKeyEqual

Just can not figure out the right syntax.

Comment: Why can't you declare those functions in the header? What details about them, would be exposed? Signatures of Hash/KeyEqual functions are fixed anyway..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think if it's declared, then that means everyone including the header can use it, right? Strictly speaking, that's not what we want. We just want the user to be able to insert and lookup the set.

Comment: So, what is the difference to you, if user uses the functions indirectly, via the set operations, or directly, by calling them? The user uses the functions in both cases.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius In terms of functionality, they are the same. But I think it's more related to isolation/encapsulation, right? Let's say if the user can see the MyTypeHash/MyTypeKeyEqual, then he can use the them for something else. For example, implement his own set by building some extra logics on top of the two functions. This is not what we want. We want them to directly use our set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done with `typedef`.  The user of `MyTypeSet` needs to be able to see complete definitions for `MyType`, `MyTypeHash`, and `MyTypeKeyEqual` in order to know how to compile `MyTypeSet`.

There are a few approaches in use to demarcate the public interface of templated code from the implementation details:

- Put the implementation details in another header ("MyTypeImpl.hpp") that is included in the public header.
- Put the private implementation types in a namespace named `detail`, `private`, or similar.
- Mangle the private names with underscore characters, as in `MyTypeHash_`.  (This can be seen a good bit in the MSVC standard library).

If it is absolutely imperative to keep `MyTypeHash` and `MyTypeKeyEqual` secret, then one could declare `MyTypeSet` as a class that only has the methods needed by the end user.  Then `MyTypeSet` could use the [pImpl idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) to have a `std::unordered_set` as a member variable visible only in the source file.  All of the methods of `MyTypeSet` would be implemented by calling into the `std::unordered_set`.

Such a `MyTypeSet` cannot have exactly the same public interface as `std::unordered_set`, because `std::unordered_set` exposes its hash and key types as member types.